# batch script - to remove duplicate tokens in file

Tags: text, batch-file

I have duplicate tokens in text file I would like to create new text file without the duplicate tokens (keeping the delimiters)

The delimiter is:~@^*^@~

example file:

```
aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~xxx~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~aaa~@^*^@~bbb
```

Result should be:

```
aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~xxx
```

I [found script](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/remove-duplicate-lines-in-pure-bat/15777.html) that remove duplicate lines:

```
==================================
@echo off > outfile
if %1'==' echo which file? && goto :eof
if not exist %1 echo %1 not found && goto :eof

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%1) do (
find "%%a" < outfile > nul
    if errorlevel 1 echo %%a >> outfile
)
```

The script work nice for duplicate lines,

So i modified the delims from:

```
 "tokens=* delims="
```

to

```
"tokens=* delims=~@^*^@~"
```

But it wont work, What am i doing wrong? is one of the delimiter characters reserved word?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: for the example you gave, what would be your expected output?

Comment: result should be:   aaa~@^*^@~bbb~@^*^@~xxx

Comment: Your delimiter is a specific sequence of multiple characters. Can any of the delimiter characters also appear in a value? For example, could @ appear in a value where it is not considered part of a delimiter?

Comment: this is the delimiter ~@^*^@~    so this is a valid sequence:   aaa~@^*^@~aa@aa~@^*^@~bbb   if you remove the delimiter its: aaa aa@aa bbb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FOR DELIMITERS option treats each *character* as a delimiter. You cannot use a sequence of characters as a delimiter, so it will not help in your case.

Windows batch is a marginal text processor for simple tasks. You have a particularly nasty problem for a Windows batch file. It might be doable, but the code would be complicated and slow *at best*.

I strongly advise you use some other tool better suited for text processing. I believe any of the following could be used:

- VBscript
- JavaScript
- Powershell
- 3rd party tools like [Gnu sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm),  perl, ... many more

Windows batch is probably about the worst choice you could make, especially for your problem. (this is coming from someone who really enjoys using batch)

Comment: Thenks dbenham, VBS is much easier i can do this with 2 arays with split  or with string and InStr function, but because of client limitations need it as batch...

Comment: You can run a VBS script from batch using CSCRIPT. Has your client disabled that capability?

Comment: @user648026 - Your file has one line, correct? What is the maximum size of the file? Batch simply cannot process a line of text that is > 8191 bytes long.

Comment: Didn't know about this limit, I think Power shell can be used, is it the same syntax as batch?

Comment: Totally different beasts. Again, I don't understand why you can't simply use VBS via the CSCRIPT batch command.